# iron-ajax response function

Tags: polymer

This works

```
        ready: function() {  
            this.response = function(e) {
                if (e.target.status == 200) {
                    this.data = e.target.response
                    this.query = ''
                }
            }.bind(this)
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open("GET", "acp.json", true)
            xhr.responseType = "json";
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
            xhr.onload = this.response
            xhr.send()
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to bind the local `this.query` to a iron-ajax response like the above?

```
<iron-ajax auto url="acp.json" last-response="[[data]]" on-response="response"></iron-ajax>

Polymer({
  is:"acp-search",
  query:"i need this",
  response: function(e) {
    if (e.target.status == 200) {
      this.query = ''
    }
  },
  ready: function() {  

  }
```

Doesn't work, query is still undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target.status` is undefined.  Use `e.detail.xhr.status`

Answer (score 1):

For `iron-ajax` the on-response function is called when the status is 200 and the info is passed in as a property of the second variable.

```
response: function(e,d) {
  var myresponse = d.response;
  console.log("the response is", myresponse);
}
```

Comment: Ok going to try if d.query is the same as this.query in the example above

Comment: nope its stil not the polymer this.query variable i want, going to try to make the question more clear

Comment: If you're just wanting query to contain the response, set last-response="{{query}}"

Comment: no query is the query on the data it gets, but mbarney found the sollution asked to paste it here but he can't so i wil paste it for him